# How can I control duplicate rows on a temporary table in ax 2009?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I am inserting records to a temp table in a while select query. I need to control that if i added the record before, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use setTmpData method on a second buffer of the same type

Example:

```
SomeTable someTable;
TmpTable  tmpTable;
TmpTable  tmpTableCheck;

// Use tmpTable as primary data set, and tmpTableCheck to check for duplicates
while select someTable
{
     tmpTable.initFromSomeTable(someTable);

     // Check if key is already used.
     tmpTableCheck.setTmpData(tmpTable);
     select firstOnly tmpTableCheck
         where tmpTableCheck.Key == tmpTable.Key;

     // Only insert record in tmpTable if the key has not been used before.
     if (! tmpTableCheck)
     {
          tmpTable.insert();
     }
 }
```

Comment: this // Check if key is already used.
     tmpTableCheck.setTmpData(tmpTable);  helped me a lot thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you have a unique index, [you can catch the problem](http://msdax.wordpress.com/2009/04/04/how-to-catch-system-exception-of-duplicate-records-found-and-show-own-message/):

```
SysInfoLogLevel prevLevel = infolog.infologLevel()
try 
{
    infolog.setInfoLogLevel(SysInfoLogLevel::None);
    whatever.insert();
    infolog.setInfoLogLevel(prevLevel); 
}
catch (Exception::DuplicateKeyException)
{
    infolog.setInfoLogLevel(prevLevel); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check for the record by before calling the insert process.

```
//Build query above
while (qr.next())
{
    SourceTable = qr.get(tablenum(SourceTable));

    select DestTable
        where DestTable.Field1 == SourceTable.Field1; //Replace with criteria that determines if records are the same

    if (!DestTable)
    {
        DestTable.Field1 = SourceTable.Field1;
        DestTable.Field2 = SourceTable.Field2;
        DestTable.Field3 = SourceTable.Field3;
        DestTable.Insert();
    }

}

//Once processing is finished
if (element.prompt())
{
    while select DestTable            
    {
        element.send(DestTable);
    }
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

Basically, try to select the record that would match what would be inserted. If no records are returned, the insert it. Otherwise it just goes to the next record.

Comment: The problem is;this query could not catch the record.       select DestTable
        where DestTable.Field1 == SourceTable.Field1; //Replace with criteria that determines if records are the same
}

Comment: I use a similar method for a report that uses a temp data source, where data is compiled from 1 or more sources. In my case, I use it as a switch to determine if I need to insert (a new record) or update (an existing record). In my application, this does work. Do you have a code snippet of the loop so we can look at the actual application?